# Why are logs not used for testing?

Tags: testing, acceptance-testing, functional-testing, integration-testing

In tests, state verification or collaboration verification is usually undertaken. One of the drawbacks of this approach is the coupling of tests to the design of constructs. Consequently, when business-specific signals exist in the application - for instance, at the debug level of logs - verification could be focused solely on these signals (such as through correlation_id for a test). This allows for more flexible design changes. Awareness of the "test the behavior, not the implementation" advice is acknowledged without delving into the ongoing debate surrounding it.

The specific inquiry revolves around:

- Why logs are not utilized for testing?
- Whether any research has investigated this matter.
- Any experiences from teams or companies regarding this approach.

An instance of this approach that has been observed is in Klarna's snabbkaffe for Erlang, which facilitates this functionality.

Comment: HInt: to avoid closing of your question, don't claim that *"logs not used for testing"* - you have no idea of this is true or false, so don't make such biased assumptions. Instead, ask something along the lines of "can logs be used for testing", and in the question's body, write something like "I have seen only very few examples of logs used for this purpose". That is something objectively true, whilst your current claim may simply be wrong.

Comment: @DocBrown questions in need of a [frame challenge](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6842/17876) are still answerable. They are in fact preferable to useless meaningless questions that aren’t even wrong.

Comment: @candied_orange: I am sure when the author of this question would invest a little bit more time into the question, remove the nonsense out of it and give a little bit more context, it does not have to be a frame challenge for us.

Comment: ... and as long as the question is closed, it stops others from guessing around what the OP could have meant. I will be happy to cast a reopen vote after the questions gets improved.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I made some mistakes - of different categories. Those aside, the core of this question was the `business-specific signals`, not the logs. The logs here are just the seemingly "easiest" way to gather those signals (and I have used/played-around this idea before, like for testing replaying events of an event-sourced aggregate and verify the logs against some previous logs). I will try to re-phrase the question - when I have more thoughts and time. I was hasty once - and it did not work.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian: I guess you have to explain "business-specific signals" by a few examples, that's a very vague term with no canonical meaning, as long as you don't mean [POSIX signals](https://dsa.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/oj/static/unix_signal.html),

Comment: This question is [discussed on meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9554/is-it-wrong-for-a-question-to-be-wrong)

Answer (score 3):

> Why logs are not utilized for testing?

Timestamps.

Testing is about verifying expectations. Record a golden log to regression test against and when you run it again in a test all the times are wrong.

Churn.

Often many things write to the same log. Those things may change independently. They may say what they say without needing to be be perfectly in sync with each other.

Logging levels

[Unit tests](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=126923) shouldn’t require configuration manipulation to work.

Thus it can be more reliable to test that these things each send the log messages they should rather than testing the log they create.

But, writing a test that you get the log you expect isn’t unheard of. It’s just often a pain. The best tests are at least deterministic if not functional. Logs are I/O. Very side effecty.

> Whether any research has investigated this matter.

That’s a resource request. We don’t do that here.

> Any experiences from teams or companies regarding this approach.

Can’t speak for everyone but you’ll find my experience above.

Comment: Your first two arguments are standing on thin ice. A log can typically be designed in a way filtering out timestamps is a no-brainer, and when different components write to the same log, a category should be included into the log entries (not just for testing, but for making it easier to analyse the log stream afterwards).

Comment: @DocBrown I wasn’t claiming they made it impossible. Just a pain. A pain that can be avoided by testing that log messages are sent rather than testing the log. But of course doing that has its own pain.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, only your examples don't convince me. Time stamps and mixed output in one log are just symptoms of a bigger hurdle - that log files are typically not designed to be machine-readable to the degree an automated test would require. I was tempted to write an answer on my own along those lines, but I still think the OP should first improve their question.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a simpler answer.

Code that runs without error, shouldn't log anything.

If you test from the logs, you are going to need lots of old skool style

```
Console.WriteLine("stage 2 reached ok!") 
Console.WriteLine("intermediate calculation results is {x}!")
```

log messages so that you verify your code is running correctly.

Comment: Depends on the log level. For application logs logging the config on startup and milestones is quite common. If it's a single-run log for a foreground application, quite a lot more might get logged.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to clutter up the answer with too much stuff. I'm sure there are things you _could_ test with logs, but I think if you just adopt that method, you will end up logging stuff just to test, which is a backwards step